# Facade pattern - request flow

Tags: java, design-patterns, facade, mediator

I know that Facade pattern is used to provide the simpler interface by hiding the complex subsystem interactions.

I am referring the below wikipedia uml on Facade pattern:

[image]

**Are the communications/calls to the Facade are uni-directional requests i.e., only Client1/Client2 sends a request and receive the response from Facade, 
but the Facade can't initiate a request to Client1/Client2 ?**

**Am I correct in saying that Facade provides uni-directional (Client -> Facade) request interactions (by simpler interface) where as Mediator facilitates the bidirectional (Client <-> Mediator) interactions across the systems/classes ?**

**Can you provide a reference which stresses on this point ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on both counts. Here is the pertinent quote, directly from the GoF book, page 282 (emphasis mine).

> Facade differs from Mediator in that it abstracts a subsystem of objects
>   to provide a more convenient interface. **Its protocol is unidirectional**; that is, Facade objects make requests of the subsystem classes but not vice versa. In
>   contrast, Mediator enables cooperative behavior that colleague objects don't or
>   can't provide, **and the protocol is multidirectional**.

Also note that Facade is classified as a *structural* pattern, whereas Mediator is a *behavioral* pattern. If a Facade could initiate requests, that would make it behavioral.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Are the communications/calls to the Facade are uni-directional
>   requests i.e., only Client1/Client2 sends a request and receive the
>   response from Facade, but the Facade can't initiate a request to
>   Client1/Client2 ?

Correct. That's why they are known as clients. The Facade class is the actual server(don't unnecessarily mix with a web server stories) who does the work for the clients. A Facade is meaningful when the client doesn't need to know what actually happens but just a high level abstraction.

Ex:

```
public class Bulb{

    public void on(){
        //logic to turn on the bulb.
    }

    public void off(){
        //logic to turn off the bulb.
    }

}

public class Fan{

    public void on(){
        //logic to turn on the fan.
    }

     public void off(){
        //logic to turn off the fan.
    }

}

public class Room{

   private Bulb bulb;
   private Fan fan;

   public void powerOff(){
        this.bulb.off();
        this.fan.off();
   }
}
```

In this example as a client I just want to call `room.powerOff();` . I am not interested in what happens internally.

> (2) Am I correct in saying that Facade provides uni-directional
>   (Client -> Facade) request interactions (by simpler interface) where
>   as Mediator facilitates the bidirectional (Client <-> Mediator)
>   interactions across the systems/classes ?

(a) Facade provides uni-directional (Client -> Facade) request interactions (by simpler interface) -> correct.

(b) Mediator facilitates the bidirectional (Client <-> Mediator) interactions -> Correct. It is something like clients are also subsystems (in Facade). :))

Comment: Thanks, but can you provide a reference which stresses on this point ?

Comment: Facade -> https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade
Mediator -> https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator